# Can't select price range (Selenium + Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have a small test case:

- Open the browser
- Enter the URL “http://practice.automationtesting.in/shop/”
- Adjust the filter by price between 150 to 450.

I tried to use ActionChains, but no result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://practice.automationtesting.in/shop/")
driver.maximize_window()
slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='woocommerce_price_filter-2']/form/div/div[1]/span[2]")
move = ActionChains(driver)
move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(10, 0).release().perform()
```

Can someone explain, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems you can find the slider simply by using class name (ui-slider-handle). What is the result when you run your code?

Comment: João Farias, when I use class_name("ui-slider-handle"), only the firs selector is moved. So I verified using "assert" if my slider (by xpath) is visible, and I received no error. Then I changed the last line of code: move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(-28, 0).release().perform() And I selected from range 150 to 451. Unfortunately, I can't select exactly to 450.

Comment: João Farias, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can find the slider simply by using class name:

[image]

```
sliders = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ui-slider-handle") #Selecting all sliders
left_slider = sliders[0]
right_slider = sliders[1]
move = ActionChains(driver)
# Moving the left slider
move.click_and_hold(left_slider).move_by_offset(10, 0).release().perform()
# Moving the right slider
move.click_and_hold(right_slider).move_by_offset(-28, 0).release().perform()
```

Comment: It's working just fine. Thank you.

Comment: Most welcome rodut. Could you mark the answer as accepted? It really motivates contributors.

Comment: Yes, sure. Thank you.